# In Java: Assigning array elements to variables outside of the array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Fairly new to stackoverflow, but I've found that a lot of the answers here thoroughly explain why something is supposed to happen - and not happen.

I'm doing my own Java practice and ran into a question asking me to:

> Assume  that the array  arr has been declared . Write a statement 
>   that assigns  the next to last   element  of the array  to the
>   variable  x , which has already  been declared .

I get how to assign each individual element one by one in a for-loop, but I don't get how to individually pick one element out and assign it without touching the other elements.

-And no, this is not a homework assignment; it's my own study during my summer break.

Thanks - NP

Comment: Hint #1:  What's the last element in an array?  How would you reference it?  Hint #2:  What would it take to get the next-to-last element in that array?  Hint #3:  You won't need loops or any sort of iteration for this; you can do this with direct access.

Comment: Use `[]`. In particular it would be the element one less than it's `length`; hint, hint. Edit: re-read, make it two.

Comment: This is an important concept; the chief benefit of arrays (and `ArrayList`, which uses them) over linked list is exactly this property, that you can access elements directly without having to loop to get to them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I get how to assign each individual element one by one in a for-loop, but I don't get how to individually pick one element out and assign it without touching the other elements.

Note that the question asks for you to *assign* `x` *to* the array element, not the other way around (i.e. it will look like `x = ...`). As for how you'd do that, recall that you can access an array element at 0-based index `i` via `array[i]`, so now it comes down to accessing the second-to-last element, meaning we need the index of that element.

Since arrays indexes are 0-based, the index of the last element should be one less than the length of the array. In Java terms: `array.length - 1`. Therefore, the index of the second-to-last element should be one less than *that*: `array.length - 2`. Therefore, the element we're after is `array[array.length - 2]`. Hopefully you can take it from here.

Comment: your answer is awesome,and I just wanted to point out one thing cuz op asked this "I get how to assign each individual element one by one in a for-loop, **but I don't get how to individually pick one element out and assign it without touching the other elements.**"

Comment: @KickButtowski Isn't that what I described?

Comment: This is great! I now see my mistake. I was trying to assign x by using arr.length - 2 but I never put it in the brackets as an element of array arr. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @arshajii I guess u did :)

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
x = arr[arr.length - 2];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can choose an element from an array in the same way you choose from a for loop:

int x = arr[arr.length - 2]

You need to write -2 because of the way elements are stored starting at 0.